# Correct Schema.org type for very small business (like farm stalls)?

Tags: schema.org, structured-data, business

What is the correct way to markup small businesses like farm stalls?

What would be used for this? The [`Organization`](https://schema.org/Organization) from Schema.org? `LocalBusiness`? Anything else more specific?

A farm stall is not in a mall or in a shopping centre. They are normally outside of a town next to the road. They have all kinds of goodies that you can buy, not always farm-related. Some farm stalls have a section of the shop dedicated where you can eat something small and drink coffee.

How would you treat these small little shops? Like a normal organization? There can be many farm stalls in a country, province and town. Not sure if local business is to be used?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

LocalBusiness seems most appropriate here to me. The size of the organisation does not change the schema type, and you can specify the numberOfEmployees to show that it is a small organisation.

Comment: Remember I am not marketing 1 farm stall, there are going to be plenty. So in the detail page of each farm stall I will list it as a local business?

Comment: @BrendanVogt Yes